# Missing Lookup Column Including Search Form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, lookup-column, column

I was trying to create new lookup column with search form in sharepoint online (365), but the lookup column with search form is missing. i want to ask, how to add lookup column with search form? as picture below.

my lookup type

[image]

the missing lookup
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, by default, there is no the Lookup(information already on this site, including search form) type.

Check if you install a custom solution for the lookup type in the environment which the second image is from.